# Does $2^{\aleph_0}\rightarrow [\aleph_1]^2_3$ require that the continuum is weakly inaccessible?

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals, infinite-combinatorics, ramsey-theory

A classic result of Sierpiński shows that $2^{\aleph_0}\nrightarrow [\aleph_1]^2_2$, that is, there is a coloring of pairs of real numbers using two colors such that both colors appear on any uncountable set of reals.

Shelah proved [1] that the number of colors cannot be increased in general: starting with a measurable cardinal $\kappa$ in a model of GCH, there is a c.c.c. forcing $\mathbb{P}$ such that after forcing with $\mathbb{P}$, we have

- $2^{\aleph_0}=\kappa$, and
- $2^{\aleph_0}\rightarrow [\aleph_1]^2_3$,

which means that for any coloring $c$ of pairs of reals using three colors, we can find an uncountable $H$ on which $c$ assumes at most two colors.

The assumption of measurability can be weakened substantially, but I am curious if the conclusion implies that the continuum must be a weakly inaccessible (possible weakly Mahlo?) cardinal.

[1] *Shelah, Saharon*, [**Was Sierpinski right? I**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02783304), Isr. J. Math. 62, No. 2-3, 355-380 (1988). [ZBL0657.03028](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0657.03028).

Edit:  The notation used is a particular instance of “[arrow notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitary_combinatorics#Ramsey_theory_for_infinite_sets)” used to express various possible partition relations.

$\kappa\rightarrow [\theta]^\xi_\tau$ means

“if we color the $\xi$-tuples from $\kappa$ with $\tau$ colors, there is a set $H$ of cardinality $\theta$ on which the coloring omits at least one color.”

The “omits at least one color” is a very weak sort of homogeneity, and in the arrow notation it is indicated through the use of square brackets on the right side.

Comment: Would it be too far afield to define the $\to$ notation?  Is there a difference between $2^{\aleph_0} \to …$ and $[2^{\aleph_0}] \to …$?

Comment: The first is a typo.  I'll fix!